# Nontrivial examples of involute and unitary operators

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, quantum-mechanics

I am looking for an operator $T$ between the spaces of smooth functions over some interval $[a,b]$ such that for any function
$f$,

$$T(T(f)) = f$$

and $T$ is self-adjoint:
$$\langle f | T g \rangle = \langle T f | g \rangle$$

where the dot product is specified as $\langle f | g \rangle = \int_a^b f^*(x) g(x) dx$.

I am aware of simple operators such as $f(x) \to -f(x)$, $f(x) \to f(-x)$, $f(x) \to -f(-x)$.

Background: Chiral symmetry, a type of symmetry in quantum mechanics, arises from invariance under a transformation that is unitary and involutary. These transformations are generally studied in the context of finite dimensional vector spaces, where common examples are the Pauli matrices. I was wondering if it was possible to generalize this to function spaces.

Comment: Basically, there's a closed subspace $V$ such that $T(x)=x$ for $x\in V$ and $T(x)=-x$ for $x\in V^\perp$.  Any closed subspace $V$ works for this.  Another way of writing it is that $T=2P-I$ where $P$ is the orthogonal projection on $V$.

Comment: Maybe I am missing the point, but I don't see how your example works: it turns functions nonsmooth. I think $T$ in your example turns a function negative in parts of the interval and unchanged in the rest. Let $T$ flip the sign of functions for $x<0$. Applying $T$ once to $\cos(x)$ makes the resulting function discontinuous.

Comment: I mean $V$ is a closed subspace of $L^2[a, b]$.  If you want smooth functions, take the sums of smooth functions from $V$ and smooth functions from $V^\perp$.

Comment: I understand now. I admire your insight!

Answer (score 1):

The only linear possibilities are going to be unitary "half-rotations", and reflections across an eigenspace. Consider the Fractional Fourier Transform for $\alpha = \pi$ on the rotation front:

$$\begin{align}[F_\pi f](\xi)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x\pm\xi)dx\\
&=f(\pm\xi)
\end{align}
$$
In terms of reflection:

Define "hyperplane" $W=(g(x))^\perp$ of the function space,
$$\begin{align}
R_{g}f&=f-2\frac{\left\langle f,g \right\rangle}{\left\langle g,g \right\rangle}g\\
&=f-2\frac{\int_a^b f^*(x) g(x) dx}{\int_a^b g^*(x) g(x) dx}g
\end{align}
$$